# Data is repeating on filtering using searchbarcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, searchbar

I’m using `searchbarcontroller` for filter the tableview data, everything is working fine but the problem is same data is repeating on filter while using `searchbarcontroller` tableview.

Like: suppose if List of alphabets is showing on the tableview (A,B,C,D) tableViewCells then when i used searchbarcontroller on this tableview then `(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` is shows the data in repeating way

Like: if i'm search for A the searchResultTableView is showing (A,A,A,A,A,A) on tableViewCells.

But on the normal tableview data is showing normally without repeating the data.

Any one please suggest me where is the actual problem in my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.xyz.com/work.php]];
    responseDataSP=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    urlConnectionSP=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"nsurl my %@",urlConnectionSP);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"Error");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [responseDataSP setLength:0];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [responseDataSP appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseDataSP);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSError *error=nil;
    NSDictionary *dicSP=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseDataSP options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    self.totalDataSP=[dicSP objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"%@",_totalDataSP);



    totalTitleSP=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    totalImageSP=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    totalIdWalaSP=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    [_tableView reloadData];

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [_totalDataSP count];

    }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SkillsTableCell";

    SkillsTableCell *cell = (SkillsTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SkillsTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];



    }



    NSDictionary *items=nil;


    NSArray *titleSP;
    NSArray *imageSP;
    NSArray *idwalaSP;

    for(int i=0;i<[_totalDataSP count];i++){

     //   NSLog(@"the _totalDataSP is %@",[_totalDataSP count]);

        items=[_totalDataSP objectAtIndex:i];

        titleSP=[items objectForKey:@"first_name"];
        [totalTitleSP addObject:titleSP];


        imageSP=[items objectForKey:@"profile_pic"];
        [totalImageSP addObject:imageSP];

        idwalaSP=[items objectForKey:@"id"];
        [totalIdWalaSP addObject:idwalaSP];


        category_id = [items objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"id value is %@",category_id);

    }



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
            cell.nameLabel.text=[totalTitleSP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }



        //For Image
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[totalImageSP objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (data) {

                cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }];

        [cell setNeedsDisplay];
    });

    return cell;
}


- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [totalTitleSP filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController delegate methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: did you check you filtered array?

Answer (score 0):

Using Predicates with Arrays

```
   NSPredicate *sPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] 'e'"];
    [array filterUsingPredicate:sPredicate];
```

or

It display desire order without duplicates

```
NSArray *beginArray = [filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"self BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText]];
NSArray *anyArray = [filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText]];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:beginArray];
for (id obj in anyArray) {
   if (![resultArray containsObject:id]) {
      [resultArray addObject:id];
   }
}
filteredArray = resultArray;
```